# interval learning unbiased estimator

Tags: statistics, estimation, uniform-distribution

Suppose that I draw $n$ points uniformly at random from $\mathcal{U}(-a,a)$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}_+$. Denote this set of points $\{X_i\}_{i=1}^n$. Now for some $-a < x_1 < x_2 < a$, let a function $f:[-a,a] \to \{0,1\}$ according to the rule,
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}0 ~~~~~\text{if }x < x_1 \text{or } x > x_2 \\ 1 ~~~~~\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
Thus, $f$ partitions $[-a,a]$ into three intervals. Denote these three regions $R_1, R_2$ and $R_3$ so that $\sup R_1=x_1$ and $\sup R_2 = x_2$. Now, assuming that I have at least one point in each interval, I form an estimator of $x_1$ by taking the largest point in $R_1$ (denoted $y_1$) and the smallest point in $R_2$ (denoted $y_2 > y_1$), and computing $\hat{x}_1=\frac{y_2 - y_1}{2}$.

I am unsure how to begin to show that this estimator is unbiased (or even if it unbiased). Can anyone help me get started?

Comment: I think you mean $\hat{x}_1 = (y_2 + y_1)/2$.  It would also be conceptually simpler to just define $f(x)$ to be $0$ if $x<x_1$ and $1$ else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify to a single threshold $\theta \in [-a,a]$ and $f(x) = 0$ if $x<\theta$, $f(x)=1$ else.  Suppose it is given that you sample $n$ times and you get $k_1$ samples to the left and $k_2$ samples to the right, where $k_1+k_2=n$ and $k_1\geq 1$, $k_2 \geq 1$.  Let $Y_1$ be the max of those samples in the left region, and $Y_2$ is the min of those samples in the right. Your estimator is $\hat{\theta} = (Y_1+Y_2)/2$.  So you can compute:

\begin{align} 
E[\hat{\theta}|k_1, k_2] &= \frac{1}{2}E[Y_1] + \frac{1}{2}E[Y_2] \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\theta - \left(\frac{\theta + a}{k_1+1}\right)  \right) + \frac{1}{2}\left(\theta + \left(\frac{a-\theta}{k_2+1}\right)\right)\\
&=\theta -\frac{(\theta + a)}{2(k_1+1)} + \frac{(a-\theta)}{2(k_2+1)}
\end{align}

This is generally biased, but you can see the bias goes to zero as $k_1\rightarrow\infty$ and $k_2\rightarrow\infty$.

---

If you use an estimator $\hat{\theta} = \frac{(k_1+1) Y_1 + (k_2+1) Y_2}{k_1+k_2+2}$ you get:

$$ E[\hat{\theta} |k_1,k_2] = \theta - \left(\frac{2\theta}{k_1+k_2+2}\right) $$

---

Define $Y_1, Y_2$ as before, and define $Y_{max}$ and $Y_{min}$ as the max and min values sampled.  You can define a new estimator as: 
$$ \hat{\theta} = (Y_1+Y_2)/2 + (Y_{max} + Y_{min})/2 $$
Given that $k_1+k_2=n$ and $k_1\geq 1$, $k_2 \geq 1$ we get: 
$$ E[\hat{\theta}|k_1,k_2] = \theta $$ 
So this new estimator is unbiased, but it might be less accurate than the original estimator $(Y_1+Y_2)/2$.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your help. I have a question regarding your recommendation for an unbiased estimator. In particular, I am having a hard time convincing myself that it is actually unbiased. From what I can gather, the expected value of $Y_{min}$ is $(\theta-k_1 a) / (k_1 +1)$ and the expected value of $Y_{max}$ is $((k_2)a - \theta) / (k_2+1)$. When I put this all together I get that the expected value of the estimator is $\theta - (\theta+a)/(2(k_1+1)) + (a-\theta)/(2(k_2+1)) + (\theta-(k_1)a)/(2(k_1+1)) + ((k_2)a - \theta) / (2(k_2+1)) = k_2\theta / (k_2 + 1)$. Can you explain more?

Comment: Oh I figured it out. It is unbiased as claimed. Thanks!

Comment: Another unbiased estimator would be: 
$$ \frac{Y_1+Y_2}{2} -\frac{(Y_3-Y_2)}{2} + \frac{(Y_1-Y_0)}{2}  $$ 
where $Y_3$ is the second smallest sample in the right interval (being $a$ if there is no other sample in the right interval besides $Y_2$), and $Y_0$ is the second largest sample in the left interval (being $-a$ if there is no other sample besides $Y_1$).